# Which key is in use when ssh logging into my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

After a `ssh-keyscan` I opened my generated `known_hosts` file, and found that there are 3 instead of 1 key for my EC2 instance.

```
**.**.**.** ssh-rsa ******
**.**.**.** ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 ***
**.**.**.** ssh-ed25519 ***
```

Are they all being used when logging in? Can I safely delete from them if some are not used at all?